# Multi city travel to land in different locations

Tags: air-travel, tickets, international-travel

I would like to travel from A-B and B-C.
Booking 2 way tickets is too expensive. Is there another option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a open-jaw flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7585/what-exactly-is-a-open-jaw-flight)

Comment: @Tom No, usually it is A to B and C to B. For instance if you were to buy London-New York-Edinburgh, it is more logical from a revenue analyst's perspective that the fare should be constructed as half of (two UK-USA return fares) rather than one (UK-USA return)+(one USA-UK return).

Comment: @Tom Oh sorry, did not see that. You're correct of course.

Comment: Yes this is called an open jaw ticket. It is usually priced at the average of the two return fares on A-B and C-B

Answer (score 1):

Most websites will let you do multi-city (multi-destination) travel planning. As examples, there is the tab "Multi-destinations" on liligo.fr, or "Multicity" on yatra.com.