# What if I don't take my last transfer at British Airways

Tags: air-travel, europe, airport-transfer, tips-and-tricks, british-airways

The usual return ticket path is:
AMS -> LHR -> ICN
and back:
ICN -> LHR -> AMS

However now I'd like to do this:
AMS -> LHR -> ICN
ICN -> LHR, done

That way I'll end up in the UK and can take a RyanAir flight to my actual destination in Europe.

I don't believe it's possible to book these "sorta-return" tickets, but booking return would still be cheaper. I don't know why airlines can't book flexibly, but whatever.

What'll happen if I not take my last transfer? What will BA do? What will the border guards do?

Comment: Would this be a one-off dropping of the last leg, or is it something you plan to do fairly often? Also, which frequent flier program will you be crediting to, BAEC or another OneWorld one?

Comment: One off, BAEC .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most definitely bookable - it's what's called an "open jaw" ticket, and will normally be priced the same as a return ticket.  What's more, you could probably book your return flight back to your actual destination for roughly the same price, although this can vary slightly based on the actual airlines and the specific cities.

You'll find more details on these types of tickets in the answers to the following questions :

[What exactly is a open-jaw flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7585/what-exactly-is-a-open-jaw-flight)

[What are the "rules" for multi-city flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6955/what-are-the-rules-for-multi-city-flights)

[One-way versus return airfare tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets)

As far as what will happen if you do fail to take your last segment, you'll generally be fine - unless you've checked luggage.  Any luggage you check will be checked all the way through to your final destination (AMS).  When you fail to board the LHR-AMS flight, your bags will have to be removed from the plane, and you will have to spend some serious time in order to reclaim them from the airline.

There can also be issues in the case of irregular operations (ie, delays, breakdowns, etc) in which case your airline might re-route you via somewhere other than LHR in order to get to your final destination of AMS.

Again you can find more information in questions such as [Do you have to take the second leg of a domestic flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-flight)

Comment: I can't actually book it through the website. But my guess too is that it's "fine normally". Most of those questions don't actually answer European or British Airways questions, mostly about American airlines, which really do differ!
I also wasn't familiar with calling every flight a "leg", which made search ineffective.

Comment: You can book this on ba.com using the "Multi-city/stopovers" option.  Most other booking websites will have something with a similar name.

Comment: P.S. I don't think the question was answered in the other questions. They concerned American domestic flights and were not specific.
This question was specifically about BA, which warrants a more specific answer, or ideally experience from someone that actually did this on a BA flight.